# How to check ASP.NET Version loaded on a system?

Tags: asp.net

How can I check the version of `ASP.NET` that is installed on my system?

Comment: Programmatically or just what you have in your windows install?

Comment: I believe this may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161529/how-to-know-which-version-of-asp-net-it-is

Comment: @aceinthehole No, that question is about which version a project was coded against.  This is about which version is installed on the machine.

Comment: half of the answers below are about seeing which version of .net you are running. 

The other half are about the machine. 
I for one need to see the .net version i'm coding against be because i wan't to check something in asp.net source code.

Answer (score 46):

You can use

```
<%
Response.Write("Version: " + System.Environment.Version.ToString());
%>
```

That will get the currently running version. You can check the registry for all installed versions at:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET
>   Framework Setup\NDP

Comment: Great. Thank You very much guys for such a quick response. Stack Over flow Rocks.

Comment: But one question to Keyboardp. Where should i run the command you sent <% Response.Write........%>

Comment: You can create a new ASPX page and copy/paste that into your page. If you want to do it from the code-behind, then just use `
Response.Write("Version: " + System.Environment.Version.ToString() );` without the `<% %>`

Comment: This answer is the best way to check as both the "on page" script and the registry check will show v4.0 vs v4.5 differerences. If you have version 4.5 installed a Response.Write on the page will display either v4.0.30319.34209 (instead of v4.0.30319.1008) and in the registry, under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full you'll see the version v4.5.51209 (instead of v4.0.30319)

Comment: Make sure that you add this an aspx file and not a asp file or else it will not work

Answer (score 43):

You can see which version gets executed when you load the page with Google Chrome + developer tools (preinstalled) or Firefox + [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) (add-on).

I use Google Chrome:

1. Open Chrome and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open the developer tools.
2. Go to the "Network" Tab
3. Click on the small button at the bottom "Preserve log upon Navigation"
4. Load any of your pages
5. Click on the response header

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't show the differences between v4.0 and v4.5 as both run under the same X-AspNet-Version of 4.0.30319. You need to check the registry or do a Response.Write as answered by @KeyboardP.

Comment: This method permets to find out the `.NET CLR Framework` version, not the `ASP.NET` version ...

Comment: You can hide the "X-Asp-Net-Version" header quite easy as written [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/windows/285-windows-hardening-disable-the-x-aspnet-version-header.html) so this solution will not always work.

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem to find a way to check whether ASP.NET 4.5 is on the Server. Because v4.5 is in place replace to v4.0, if you look at c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework, you will not see v4.5 folder. Actually there is a simple way to see the version installed in the machine. Under Windows Server 2008 or Windows 7, just go to control panel -> Programs and Features, you will find "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5" if it is installed.

Answer (score 4):

Look in c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework and you will see various folders starting with "v" indicating the versions of .NET installed.

Comment: I installed version 4.5 and that version does NOT show up under the Framework directory. So your solution isn't correct.

Comment: If it exists, did you check c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\FFramework64

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that will return the installed .NET details:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.IO" %>
<% 
Dim cmnNETver, cmnNETdiv, aspNETver, aspNETdiv As Object
Dim winOSver, cmnNETfix, aspNETfil(2), aspNETtxt(2), aspNETpth(2), aspNETfix(2) As String

winOSver = Environment.OSVersion.ToString
cmnNETver = Environment.Version.ToString
cmnNETdiv = cmnNETver.Split(".")
cmnNETfix = "v" & cmnNETdiv(0) & "." & cmnNETdiv(1) & "." & cmnNETdiv(2)

For filndx As Integer = 0 To 2
  aspNETfil(0) = "ngen.exe"
  aspNETfil(1) = "clr.dll"
  aspNETfil(2) = "KernelBase.dll"

  If filndx = 2   
    aspNETpth(filndx) = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), aspNETfil(filndx))
  Else
    aspNETpth(filndx) = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "Microsoft.NET\Framework64", cmnNETfix, aspNETfil(filndx))
  End If

  If File.Exists(aspNETpth(filndx)) Then
    aspNETver = Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(aspNETpth(filndx))
    aspNETtxt(filndx) = aspNETver.FileVersion.ToString
    aspNETdiv = aspNETtxt(filndx).Split(" ")
    aspNETfix(filndx) = aspNETdiv(0)
  Else
    aspNETfix(filndx) = "Path not found... No version found..."
  End If
Next

Response.Write("Common MS.NET Version (raw): " & cmnNETver & "<br>")
Response.Write("Common MS.NET path: " & cmnNETfix & "<br>")
Response.Write("Microsoft.NET full path: " & aspNETpth(0) & "<br>")
Response.Write("Microsoft.NET Version (raw): " & aspNETtxt(0) & "<br>")
Response.Write("<b>Microsoft.NET Version: " & aspNETfix(0) & "</b><br>")
Response.Write("ASP.NET full path: " & aspNETpth(1) & "<br>")
Response.Write("ASP.NET Version (raw): " & aspNETtxt(1) & "<br>")
Response.Write("<b>ASP.NET Version: " & aspNETfix(1) & "</b><br>")
Response.Write("OS Version (system): " & winOSver & "<br>")
Response.Write("OS Version full path: " & aspNETpth(2) & "<br>")
Response.Write("OS Version (raw): " & aspNETtxt(2) & "<br>")
Response.Write("<b>OS Version: " & aspNETfix(2) & "</b><br>")
%>
```

Here is the new output, cleaner code, more output:

```
Common MS.NET Version (raw): 4.0.30319.42000
Common MS.NET path: v4.0.30319
Microsoft.NET full path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe
Microsoft.NET Version (raw): 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
Microsoft.NET Version: 4.6.1586.0
ASP.NET full path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
ASP.NET Version (raw): 4.7.2110.0 built by: NET47REL1LAST
ASP.NET Version: 4.7.2110.0
OS Version (system): Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0
OS Version full path: C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
OS Version (raw): 10.0.14393.1715 (rs1_release_inmarket.170906-1810)
OS Version: 10.0.14393.1715
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can create a button on your webpage and in the Page_Load type;

```
Trace.IsEnabled = True
```

And in the button click event type;

```
Response.Write(Trace)
```

This will bring up all the trace information and you will find your ASP.NET version in the "Response Headers Collection" under "X-ASPNet-Version".

Comment: You can hide the "X-Asp-Net-Version" header quite easy as written [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/windows/285-windows-hardening-disable-the-x-aspnet-version-header.html) so this solution will not always work.

Answer (score 2):

open a new command prompt and run the following command:
dotnet --info

Answer (score 1):

I needed this information too and got information with this method,

Launch PowerShell

run the 'import-module servermanager' command ( without quotes )

after that for asp.net 3.5 check
run the 'get-windowsfeature web-asp-net' command ( without quotes )

for asp.net 4.5 check
run the 'get-windowsfeature Net-Framework-45-Core' command ( without quotes )

Both of the commands will inform you below Install State header.

Detecting version via GUI in server environment and details can be found [in this link.](https://help.duo.com/s/article/3601?language=en_US)

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe the amount of overly complicated and convoluted answers one after the other in this thread.

Simply open your terminal and run:

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
```

The command will list all .Net runtimes installed and detected on your system, among which Asp.Net runtimes.

As an example, here is the output on my system:

```
me@myhost $ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```