# Missing ASP.NET 5 Templates

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am following this setup tutorial

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html#create-a-new-asp-net-5-project

And have come across a problem. In the tutorial the instructions are as follows:

> Start Visual Studio 2015. From the File menu, select New > Project.
>
> Select the ASP.NET Web Application project template. It appears under
>   Installed > Templates > Visual C# > Web. Name the project ContosoBooks
>   and click OK.

This is fine, but in the next step :

> In the New ASP.NET Project dialog, select Web Application under
>   ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates. Also, make sure the Host in the cloud
>   checkbox is not selected and click OK.

I am seeing no ASP.NET 5 Preview templates!

[image]

The only thing I am noticing is that my Authentication states **No Authentication** but I am signed in so I am not sure what this means or whether or not this is a factor.

The version I have installed of Visual Studio is "Community 2015".

I have already gone through the perquisites as outlined in [This Article](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html).

I am hoping that someone with a more thorough knowledge on the topic can help me out as I have not been able to find any threads etc. of the same issue or what could be causing the Templates to be missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have concluded, by following another stackoverflow question on [How to check the ASP.NET version loaded on a system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969071/how-to-check-asp-net-version-loaded-on-a-system) as I noticed that the templates were categorized in the ASP.NET versions (4.6.1 & 5) in the tutorials but mine were not.

So I then checked and my files in **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework** are as follows
[image]

Revealing no v5.0 directory. I rectified this and now all of the templates are available

*AMENDMENT:*

To fix it:

I went to http://www.asp.net/downloads and downloaded **ASP.NET MVC 5**

I ensured I had Developer Tools checked in the download process.

This issue was now resolved - As I then had the MVC 5 template files. Because I downloaded them, so I had them... and no longer didn't have them.

*ALTERNATE FIX:*

Furthermore From my research, some people had not included *Developer Tools*. To resolve: go to old mate 'Add or remove programs' and find your Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx install, 'change' and install Microsoft Web Developer Tools

Comment: Can you add how you "rectified" the situation?

Comment: and how did you fix it?

Comment: I have now added an amendment for further clarification

Comment: If you're voting down on how I resolved my OWN issue then provide an explanation or comment first

Comment: Your amendment does not clarify the previous commenter's question about how you resolved the issue. The link you provided is to a project tutorial download...

Comment: Thanks, further amended and link removed

Answer (score 19):

Asp.net 5 templates no longer exist - they are renamed to Asp.net Core: [ASP.NET 5 is dead - Introducing ASP.NET Core 1.0 and .NET Core 1.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx)

So, when creating your project, instead of picking "*ASP.NET Web Application*" as it is in the video - you would select **"ASP.NET Core Web Application**" and then on the next page those 3 templates (Empty, Web API, Web Application) are the same as the video's asp.net 5 preview templates

Comment: From this link it states: "This blog post is announcing this change. It's not done or released yet. As of the date/time of this writing, this work is just starting. It will be ongoing over the next few months." And this post is dated a couple of weeks after this question was asked. Fair to assume that many people will still be in the same environment as original post and will maintain it's value either way, but thanks for the update nonetheless

Answer (score 9):

VS 2015 Preview is going under *ASP.net Core web application*. If you cant see that one under templates you may go to [this](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows) site and download **.NET Core 1.0 for Visual Studio** then install.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem but it is actually even better because "The new dialog enables you to change the default authentication options for many of the templates. For example, when you create an ASP.NET Web Forms project you can select any of the following options:

No Authentication
Individual User Accounts (ASP.NET membership or social provider log in)
Organizational Accounts (Active Directory in an internet application)" 
check out this >>  http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem and finally fixed it by uninstalling (control panel -> uninstall a program) Microsoft.NET Core and Microsoft Visual C++ redistrutable 2015 (x64 & x86) and then re-installing the asp.net core rc2 (https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows or possibly check Tools->Extensions and Updates->Updates inside of Visual Studio).

I uninstalled the Visual C++ redistrutables because I kept getting an error when trying to re-install asp.net core rc2. It kept telling me that it already existed even after I had just uninstalled it and the update was showing in the "Extensions and Updates" section of Visual Studio after trying (but failing) to install the asp.net core rc2 update.